# TFS commands in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, tfs

I have a Powershell script written in the version 1.0. In this existing old script I need the facility to get the latest code of a project from TFS. I have TFS client on the machine and that lets me use the TFS command line. I have created the TFS command line comments to get the latest from TFS. These commands run successfuly from the command propmt.

Now the I need to include these TFS commands in my old poweshell script. I need to know if this is doable? If yes then how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option is to run the [TF.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) program with the necessary arguments from within your PowerShell script, as you would with any other executable:

```
PS> & "$env:ProgramFiles\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" @("workspace", "/new", "WS1", "/noprompt", "/login:foo,bar", "/collection:baz/tfs")
```

Or you could use the TFS PowerShell cmdlets included in the [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f):

```
PS> Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell 
PS> Get-TfsChangeset -Latest -Server "http://mytfsserver"
```

Comment: Thanks Enrico. I would go with the option 1. I have the tfs commands ready. As I am very new to powershell, I am wondering how do I put those in the powershell script.

Say this is my command to create a workspace
"%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" workspace /new WS1 /noprompt /login:xxxx,xxxx /collection:http://xxxx/tfsxxx

How do I put this is powershell script. Please advise.

Comment: Thanks much. A little change in the syntax, it expects '/new' & 'ws1' seperated by comma 

PS> & "$env:ProgramFiles\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" @("workspace", "/new", "WS1", "/noprompt", "/login:foo,bar", "/collection:baz/tfs")