# Running TFS commands with arguments in powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs, tf-cli

Hi I am trying to run the "tf get" command through powershell but i always get a unexpected token error when it reaches the arugments.

I was following the instructions from this post 
[TFS commands in PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588678/tfs-commands-in-powershell-script)

the line where the error is happening is

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" @("get", $args[$i])
```

where $args[$i] is an argument being entered by the user, but the script stops executing after calling the tf.exe

Could someone help me out here? Thanks.

Comment: add the full error to your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't execute a command in a string without using the call operator e.g. `&`.  In PowerShell a string evaluates to a string e.g.:

```
C:\> "hello world"
hello world
```

You have to tell PowerShell that the string contains the name of a command using the call operator.

```
$tf = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe'
& $tf get $args[$i]
```

Note: when using `&` the string must contain just the name of the command. Arguments should be specified separately.